# How do I force cursor to always be in one form field using HTML5/Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I am trying to keep the focus always on one form field.  It basically needs to always be active on the page so if anything is typed it is always into this field.  How do I accomplish this?  I have used the autofocus command from HTML5 but once I switch it does not go back without page refresh.  Basically I want the cursor to be forced to always stay in that form field?

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Type Here" id="forced" required autofocus>
```

This all must be controlled on the client end so only HTML5 and Javascript can be used.  Is there a solution for this?

Comment: Please clarify, is jQuery within the allowable parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do what you're trying to do. I'm listening for the `blur` event and re-focusing the input when it happens. Here is plain javascript if you don't want the overhead of jQuery for something so simple.

```js
var alwaysFocusedInput = document.getElementById( "focus_target" );

alwaysFocusedInput.addEventListener( "blur", function() {
  setTimeout(() =>{
    alwaysFocusedInput.focus();
  }, 0);
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="focus_target" placeholder="always focused" autofocus />
<input type="text" placeholder="some other input" />
```

You could just stick `alwaysFocusedInput.focus();` at the end of your script as @3D1TOR suggested.

Or if you want to support really old Firefox:

Try putting this script I found [here](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/15020/why-doesnt-autofocus-autofocus-work-in-mozilla-firefox) at the bottom of your body element for older versions of Firefox.

```
<script>
    if (!("autofocus" in document.createElement("input"))) {
        document.getElementById("focus_target").focus();
    }
</script>
```

Comment: If I click anything else on the page the cursor does not return to the form input unless I click there.

Comment: Click anywhere in the iframe of the example. That code will work on your page. If you try to click the other input or anywhere within the border of the snippet it will work. That snippet is like a document inside a document.

Comment: Maybe I am misunderstanding.  I copy this code verbatim putting the JS in the script tags and test the page and it does not work.  Am I missing something?

Comment: Did you include the code for the input that has the corresponding id? Or change the id?

Comment: I just made an html page with the exact code above but putting the javascript code in script and /script tags in the header.  Perhaps I am missing something?

Comment: You would need to put the code in a script tag below the creation of the input element in your body. If you have your script in the head of your document, it is running the code before the input that it is looking for is even created.

Comment: Ok, let me try that.

Comment: Like the other option, it works in Chrome but not FireFox.

Comment: Ok so if you click into the input it will start working, but FF is having a problem with autofocus. I will figure this out and get back to you. FF has problems transitioning focus between things.

Comment: That script is only for browsers that don't support autofocus. FF (at least new versions of it) do support it. I would just leave it off, and add `alwaysFocusedInput.focus()` to the end of your first script. (Just tack it on the end.)

Comment: That would have to be older than FF 4, which is really old, and either way, running `alwaysFocusedInput.focus()` isn't going to hurt no matter what version of what browser he's using.

Comment: Updated the mention of "for older version of Firefox" in response to your comment @3D1TOR. I think they might have an older version.

Comment: Yup, won't hurt!

Answer (score 0):

You could try this..

```
$("#forced").blur(function(){
      $(this).focus();       
});
```

Comment: this does not work however, if I click anything else on the page the cursor does not return to the form input unless I click there.

Comment: I just worked up a Fiddle. It works on there. Check it out.
https://jsfiddle.net/difster/9nmpq0xm/

Comment: This works on Chrome but not Firefox, is that correct?

Comment: Your'e right, it does not work in FF. I hadn't checked that before now.

Comment: I've tried a couple of solutions I've seen out there and I can't get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Focus the element when anything that isn't the element is focused.

```
$(":not('#forced')").focus(function(){
  $("#forced").focus();       
});
```

Answer (score -2):

```
function autoFocus() 
{
    inputTxt = document.getElementById("forced").autofocus;    
}
autoFocus();
```

Comment: This answer doens't solve the problem. Indeed it doens't solve nothing.